# why sometimes we need to use Broadband Transmission (Using Modulation)?

Tags: analog, digital-communications, bandwidth

I was reading a textbook which says:

***Baseband transmission requires that we have a low-pass channel, a channel with a bandwidth that starts from zero. This is the case if we have a dedicated medium(such as coaxial or fiber optic cable) with a bandwidth constituting only one channel. For example, the entire bandwidth of a cable connecting two computers is one single channel.***

I'm a little bit confused, if dedicated medium means low-pass channel, why we still need Broadband Transmission (Using Modulation) to have bandpass channel—a channel with a bandwidth that does not start from zero and we need to convert the digital signal to an analog signal before transmission. Because for example, broadband transmission using modulation is the sending of computer data througha telephone subscriber line, the line connecting a resident to the central telephone office.

Isn't the subscriber line also a dedicated medium, connecting a user and telephone office?

Comment: Yes but its baseband channel is already taken ... for voice communications by old fashioned telephone.

Comment: @BrianDrummond sorry I don't get it. isn't that telephone subscriber line also a dedicated medium and a dedicated medium mean low-pass channel?

Comment: Yes that's the point A subscriber line is a dedicated TELEPHONE line. So its baseband channel is connected to the telephone. That means to run broadband across THE SAME line, it must be modulated on a higher frequency channel.

Comment: @BrianDrummond  Thanks for your answer. I think I knid of get it. So you mean since the telephone has taken the subscriber line, so for other usage like networking usage, we need to have broadband. But just a small question. when telephone is not in use, can't we consider the subscriber line is a dedicated medium for sth else then?

Comment: @amjad If you send a signal in the telephone part of the channel, how does the telephone switch know that you're not trying to make a telephone call?

Comment: Do you understand why we use modulation for radio transmission?

Comment: @user253751 but even modulating another signal on a higher frequency,  can the telephone switch know that this is not a telephone call?

Comment: @amjad well maybe, but then they would need to upgrade all their telephone switches

Comment: Multiply posted at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/68865 .